# java 8 : How to use Stream with Hashmap and List

Tags: list, foreach, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I'm beginner with `java 8`,  I have a `list` of String and a `Hashmap<String,String>`.
My code in `java 7` version and I want to transform it with new functionalities of `java 8` like `stream` and `forEach` :

```
    Map<String, String> mapPeriod = new HashMap<>();

    mapPeriod.put("10", "Q1");
    mapPeriod.put("20", "Q2");
    mapPeriod.put("30", "Q3");
    mapPeriod.put("40", "Q4");

List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<LabelValue> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s: listOne ) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapPeriod.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(s)) {
                LabelValue lv = new LabelValue();
                lv.setLabel(entry.getValue());
                lv.setValue(entry.getKey());
                lv.setChecked(false);
                listTwo.add(lv);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental design problem in your prerequisites. You should map from key to value, not vice versa. Your design requires this inefficient repeated linear search for the matching entry and has unclear policies regarding potential duplicates.

Comment: @Holger "You should map from key to value, not vice versa" : I didn't understand you, how to map from key to value ?

Comment: Since you want to look up `"Q1"` etc, use `Map<String, String> mapPeriod = new HashMap<>(); mapPeriod.put("Q1", "10"); mapPeriod.put("Q2", "20"); mapPeriod.put("Q3", "30"); mapPeriod.put("Q4", "40");`. Then, you can simply perform a lookup instead of looping over the entries, in other words, you can use the map in the intended way: `for(String s: listOne) { LabelValue lv = new LabelValue(); lv.setLabel(s); lv.setValue(mapEriod.get(s)); lv.setChecked(false); listTwo.add(lv); }` Add an appropriate constructor to the `LabelValue` class and the loop will become a one-liner.